# Quartz cron expression to run at a different time on Saturday

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I understand how to generate a cron expression to run at certain times for each day, and I have it right now go at noon and 15:30 MON-SAT. However I would like it to be at 15:00 on Saturday instead of 15:30. Is there some method to writing this out as a cron expression? Or do I need to do a separate trigger for Saturday?

Comment: No, I suggest you to create additional trigger

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you know how to create cron expression, as per the question, you already have a scheduler to run the job at 15.30 from Mon to SAT. If you have a requirement to run a scheduler only on Saturday at 15.00 time, I will suggest you to create another one. It will be cohesive and it makes sensible for each time what is happening. If you want to change the time from Mon to Sat, you can change the cron expression from 15.30 to 15.00.